# Symfony routing w/ regex

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I have some legacy routes which I need to emulate in S4:

```
/**
 * @Route("/service.php/application/procedure")
 */
```

This didn't work because the '.' in service.php I assume - so next I tried using regex:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{foobar}/application/procedure", requirements={"foobar"="[a-zA-Z.-]+"})
 */
```

This didn't work either - I can't change the `service.php` to anything as the front end of this application is done in extJS and client-side tools.

Comment: can you post the error or something? i have no issue with the first definition @Route("/service.php/application/procedure") is working in my envoirment

Comment: What version of Symfony? Mine is 4.0.10 not sure whether that matters but I swear I've done this before months ago - when I was confirming what I want to do now was possible :o

Comment: 4.0.8 but that should work in both

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need this regex, the documentation says:

> By default, the Symfony Routing component requires that the parameters match the following regular expression: [^/]+. This means that all characters are allowed except /.

[How to Allow a "/" Character in a Route Parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

Comment: I tried that as well - didn't work - still results in a 404 "The requested resource /rpi/service.php/application/procedure/list was not found on this server." If I drop the "." everything works fine

Comment: This legacy route was used before you began to use Symfony right?

Comment: Yes - this program is 10 years old - I am reworking Symfony into the backend to modernize the application stack. I figured out the issue - I am using PHP built-in server for development and these URI's would require a customer router which inadvertently causes issues my xdebug. So I either swallow this issue and rename the URI or I upgrade my VM to use NGINX or similar

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me that it is the built-in PHP server that is causing the issue not Symfony. :o